# Changed profiles; lost Ubuntu; how do I get it back?

Tags: user-profile

Installed Ubuntu-secure-remix 12.10 in a dual boot with Windows 8 on an HP laptop. A first-time Linux user, I was exploring settings when I changed profiles (not sure what I changed it to). Now the Linux boots into what I believe is the shell. I can still log in (that is, I am already a user - so that's still there). Due possibly to using rEFInd, I cannot figure how to run Ubuntu in recovery mode. How can I get Ubuntu back up and running again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu secure remix is not an official ubuntu distro. Hence it is offtopic here

Comment: @Tachyons Ubuntu Secure Remix is an unofficial *installer*, not an unofficial operating system. The consequence of installing it is an official Ubuntu system (which is probably why [it has documentation on the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix)). Since it's not its own operating system *once installed*, and the problem here is happening on a system *that has been installed*, **this question is on-topic and should not be closed**. (I know of no precedent to close this. If you think still think this should be closed, I recommend posting on meta.)

Comment: I erased the Ubuntu OS and started over. It works now.